# For each of the following functions f find a simple function g such that f(n)=Θ(g(n)) (Skiena's Algorithm Design Manual)

Tags: big-o

I am doing exercises from Skiena's Algorithm Design Manual, and I am not sure about 2.30. Would you say my solutions are correct?
[a link to the screenshot of the exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvL9D.png)

1. 4^n
2. n
3. log(n^20)
4. (0.99)^n

Thank you so much for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Numbers 1 and 4 are correct, whereas 2 and 3 are not.

- 2: should be `n log n`, because `log n > (constant)`.
- 3: should be `(log n)^10`, because `log (n^20) = 20 log n`, which is smaller.